# Dynamic DBGrid Cell coloring

Tags: delphi

I'm using Delphi XE-2 and DBGrid from Jedi component group (TJvDBGrid). Now, I found it to be very easy to define cell color when values are known, for example:

```
OnGetCellParams event: 
if DBGrid.Field.AsInteger = 0
then Background := clYellow;
```

but in my case, user can define what value will have what color, that is stored on separate table. And my question, is there a way to color cell by looking up if cell value has a color assign to it?

I would appreciate any help or guidance in the matter, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to use the form's `OnCreate` to populate an array, and then access that in the `OnGetCellParams` event. The array should contain as many items as there are possible values, plus a default value for array index 0 in case a color hasn't been assigned. (Untested, off-the-cuff code follows!)

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ...
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FColors: array of TColor;
  end;

implementation

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  NumRows, i: Integer;
begin
  // One row for each possible value for the integer column you're
  // trying to color the cell for (eg., if the table can hold a value
  // from 0-10, you need the same # of items in the array (array[0..10])
  NumRows := NumberOfPossibleValues;
  SetLength(FColors, NumberOfPossibleValues);

  // Pre-fill the array with the default clWindow color,
  // in case a custom color isn't assigned to a value
  // (for instance, the user doesn't set a color for a value
  // of 7).
  for i := 0 to High(FColors) do
    FColors[i] := clWindow;  

  // Assumes your color values are in a database called FieldColors,
  // in a datamodule called dmAppData, and that there's a
  // column named ColValue indicating the `Field.AsInteger`
  // value and the corresponding TColor stored as an integer.
  dmAppData.FieldColors.First;
  while not dmAppData.FieldColors.Eof do
  begin
    i := dmAppData.FieldColors.FieldByName('ColValue').AsInteger;

    // Might want to put a check here to make sure the value isn't
    // more than the number of items in the array!!!
    FColors[i] := TColor(dmAppData.FieldColors.FieldByName('Color').AsInteger);
    dmAppData.FieldColors.Next;
  end;
end;
```

In your `OnGetCellParams` event:

```
Background := FColors[DBGrid.Field.AsInteger];
```

You might want to use a local variable in the `OnGetCellParams` to make sure you stay within the array bounds:

```
Background := clWindow;
i := DBGrid.Field.AsInteger;
if (i > 0) and (i < Length(FColors)) then
  Background := FColors[i];
```

The much slower way would be to do a `Locate` in the `OnGetCellParams` event for every single row:

In `OnGetCellParams`:

```
Background := clWindow;
if dmAppData.FieldColors.Locate('ColValue', DBGrid.Field.AsInteger, []) then
  Background := TColor(dmAppData.FieldColors.FieldByName('Color').AsInteger);
```

Comment: Thank you, 
given that my table will hold very limited (little) amount of data, I think I'll go with 'Locate' option. 
Interestingly, it prompts for "multiple-step operation generated errors" at runtime. I'll definitely will try 'array' approach as well.